# Changing Sprite material at runtime not applied?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am creating 2D game. I am changing the sprite material at runtime but the material remains same. My material should change with some time period but once I enter from one scene to another, the sprite material change takes place with desired material. Why this is working only when changing the scene not without changing the scene?

```
tree.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().material = newMaterial;
```

Comment: Where are you running this line of code? Start()? Update()? A custom method?

Comment: This line is in a custom method. This method is called inside update method